# Calling member function of an incomplete type compiles in gcc and does not compile in clang and msvc

Tags: visual-c++, c++17, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

Here is an example:

```
struct TestClass {
  void testFunction() const {}
  static TestClass* ptr_;
  constexpr static auto funcPtr = +[](){ ptr_->testFunction(); };
};

TestClass* TestClass::ptr_ = new TestClass();

int main() {
  TestClass::funcPtr();
  delete TestClass::ptr_;
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles in `gcc` and does not in `clang` and `msvc`. Which compiler is right? Is it a bug of `gcc`?

Here is `clang` error message:

```
<source>:4:46: error: member access into incomplete type 'TestClass'
    4 |   constexpr static auto funcPtr = +[](){ ptr_->testFunction(); };
      |                                              ^
<source>:1:8: note: definition of 'TestClass' is not complete until the closing '}'
    1 | struct TestClass {
      |        ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

`msvc` error message is the following:

```
example.cpp
<source>(4): error C2027: use of undefined type 'TestClass'
<source>(1): note: see declaration of 'TestClass'
<source>(4): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
<source>(4): note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
<source>(4): note: see usage of 'TestClass::<lambda_bdad2d00eade3d9eccb85c581305196c>::operator void (__cdecl *)(void)'
Compiler returned: 2
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in GCC. None of Clang, MSVC, Intel C++ compiler allow calling member function of an incomplete type.

Comment: your title is a little confusing, if the type was incomplete then neither of the 3 would allow it.

Comment: actually I was confused and the title was ok :D sorry

Comment: [CWG 1836](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1836.html) makes this well-formed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [CWG 1836](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1836.html) and the program is well-formed as per the current wording as explained below.

First note that `->`(and `.`) is the **member access operator** and so we move onto [expr.post#expr.ref](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.ref-4):

> Otherwise, the object expression shall be of class type.
> The class type shall be complete **unless the class member access appears in the definition of that class.**

And since `ptr_->testFinction()` is within the definition of the class, there is **no need for the class-type to be complete here**.

---

Here is the **confirmed clang bug**:

[Clang rejects valid program involving member access operator with incomplete type CWG 1836](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/83424)

Comment: @ГеоргийГуминов Yes, both clang and msvc seems wrong here. Here is the [clang bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/83424). Added the same in the answer.

Comment: What if we replace a pointer with a reference like in the [example](https://godbolt.org/z/vKE8fK9Kv)? There will be no operators.

Comment: @ГеоргийГуминов Both `.` as well as `->` are *member access operators*. So your [example](https://godbolt.org/z/vKE8fK9Kv) with reference is also well-formed for the same reason mentioned in my updated answer.